# SpriteKit: Resetting SKPhysicsBody also resets its Gravity

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have found an 'issue'/(weird interaction) with an `SKSpriteNode`'s `SKPhysicsBody`. After setting the `SKPhysicsBody`, like this:

```
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: bodies)
```

I wanted to add more physicsBodies to the node so I added it to `bodies` list and called the same line again. It turns out if you want to change the node's `SKPhysicsBody` again after initialising it, the gravity setting of the node is also reset.

What I mean by this is if the node's `affectedByGravity` variable is originally `false` and then you reset the node's physicsBody, it becomes `true`.

Even weirder, if the node's `affectedByGravity` variable is originally `true` and then you reset the node's physicsBody, the gravity acceleration of the node is reset. Therefore, the node appears to be 'stuttering' down the screen unevenly and not smoothly accelerating by the gravity.

I don't want this to occur when I reset the physicsBody of the node, I just want to change its physicsBody without it affecting its gravity at all. ANY ideas would be **GREATLY**  appreciated in ***Swift***.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually that when u reset an `SKSpritenode`'s physicsBody, it automatically sets the velocity of that physicsBody to 0. From what I have tried, you can not stop this.

However, to get around this issue save the velocity of the physicsBody before resetting the physicsBody and then set the old velocity as the new one:

```
let vel = node.physicsBody?.velocity
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: bodies)
node.physicsBody?.velocity = vel!
```

Comment: 1st, you are not "resetting" the body, you are creating a completely new body and giving it to the node (The terms used are very important to help you understand what is going on)

Comment: 2nd, I would not recommend this approach, because more than just the velocity is changing, and may end up screwing your physics entirely. (E.G. you will reset the `collisionBitMask`, so you may end up going through a wall or unintentionally bouncing off an object you were not suppose to, another E.G. While your physicsBody is being processed by the physics engine, you swap out the body, causing the app to potentially crash because the body is looking for a node that does not exist.)